# "WPF UserControl.Unloaded" tab change vs unload

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a wpf user control that displays some unmanaged resources that are expensive to create/dispose.

The UnLoaded event is the ideal event to free up unmanaged resources in, but it is called multiple times per instance due to some controls creating/destroying the visual tree.

What I would like to do is somehow determine if, in the UnLoaded event, is the control still alive and well, but without a visual tree built for it.

That way, I can prevent freeing/creating up unmanaged resources if the user is simply navigating through the TabControl, or w/e the case may be.

Comment: Please also note the following from the Remarks on the Unloaded event: `Note that the Unloaded event is not raised after an application begins shutting down. Application shutdown occurs when the condition defined by the ShutdownMode property occurs. If you place cleanup code within a handler for the Unloaded event, such as for a Window or a UserControl, it may not be called as expected.`

Comment: If my application shuts down, any memory that I wanted to free would be free anyway, so no biggy. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

The Unloaded-event is the wrong place to free unmanaged resources.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.100).aspx
When you know that the UserControl is not needed anymore and want to free unmanaged resources immediatley
 - call Dispose()